# How to construct family tree using asp.net c# and SQL server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I have a database schema. How do I construct a family tree using asp.NET, C# and SQL server? Also, how can I show you the database schema?

Comment: So what's not working for you?

Comment: i dont know how to writecode for familytree construction with database so plshelp me

Comment: How far have you got?

Comment: yestarday i got i saw some ex but not understanding help me andi have db schema

Comment: Do you know how to code in C#? Can you write T-SQL? If the answer to those is no, you should go and learn those first. I ask because the question shows very little effort on your part, like you don't really know where to start?

Comment: ya i know both already i buil one project but in tree i am new so

Comment: Well then, think about how you could build a suitable data structure. You need objects which can be associated with parents and children. Then apply this thinking to your code. Then show us what you've done, and maybe we can be of more help!

Comment: can u give one suitable example for my requirement pls.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you take a look at [Family Show](http://familyshow.codeplex.com/), a WPF application which enables you to view and/or edit a family tree. I think that with some tweaking you will be able to make it work against SQL Server using your database schema.

Comment: can u implement it give to me i ll give u db schema?

Comment: @user3535705 No, I already have a job. You either need to do it yourself or hire somebody to do it for you (I doubt anyone will do it for free)

Comment: oh thanks for your suggesation